# How do I know if the user is a customer?

Tags: php, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using Woocommerce and Dokan latest version.
I need to check if the user is a customer of that vendor. In this way, I will show the customer some information about that product or seller.
First I thought of using localstorage but realized that there is no product-specific assignment. So I think this method won't work.

So how can I know this and take action accordingly?

Comment: How does WooCommerce store the relationship between customers and vendors? Would you have to look through your current users's order history to get a list of vendors that they are customers of? (If you do, I'd cache that in a transient, and make sure you clear it / update it on a new order.) But I think you probably want to do this on the server side, not the client side, unless you're assembling the page by AJAX? (I don't know Dokan)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress have role and permission system, WordPress have following built-in roles

1 Admin privilege's 10.
2 Editor
3 Author
4 Subscriber

The Subscriber is consider as client, i mean users, you can made check on this.